# How to determine extention of a file by looking at its header/content?

Tags: dll, reverse-engineering, file-extension, portable-executable, hex-editors

I need to know the file extension, not by looking file name, but by looking at its header (file header/contents/whatever).

For example, I can determine if a file is DOS file by seeing "MZ" at the start of header; an .exe file by finding its PE header; a .dll by looking at some DLL flags every DLL file possesses etc.

But I also want to determine other extensions like if this file extension is .mui/.tlb/.api/.qtx/.... the list goes on. One common thing about all the exentions I mentioned here is that all are "PE" files and some of them are "DLL" files. (I don't need info about non-PE files)

Is it possible to determine file extension at this detail? If yes, how? What are the portions of the file which can give me exact extension of a file as we see in the file name? In other words, is extention of a file is written somewhere in the header OR is it possible to derive it?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: That's just not how it works.  A .mui file also starts with "MZ" and is a proper PE file.  So does a .fnt, .qtx, .ocx, .dll, etcetera.  The extension indicates the usage of the file, its format is secondary.  And often not documented, not discernible or ambiguous.  The only key you have is the file association in the registry.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, .mui also is a PE file starting with MZ. 
So in short, there is no(easy) way to determine the extension?
And I didn't understand what you meant by file association in the registry. :(

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible. That mechanism is _way_ out of scope of SO. Research how operating systems work, I guess.